# How to differentiate between user-change to a control (Slider) or programmatic?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a slider to change the volume, but after a user-change I fade to the new value (updating the slider with the current volume in the process). I use the sliders TAG-property to indicate the programatic change while I update its position, but somehow this still triggers my new-target-volume routine and thus cancels the whole ting. What am I doing wrong?

```
procedure TMain.VolumeBarChange(Sender:TObject);
begin
  try
    If VolumeBar.Tag=0 then Begin;
       StartVolumeFade(IncSecond(Now,3),VolumeBar.Position);
       LogWrite('Volume changed via slider.',debug);
    End else begin;
      LogWrite('Ignoring Volumebar change.',debug);
    end;
  except

  end;
end;
```

and

```
procedure TMain.UpdateVolumeBar;

Var
  CurrentVolume:Integer;

Begin;
  VolumeBar.Tag:=1;
  try
    CurrentVolume:=GetPlayerVolume;
    If CurrentVolume>-1 then Begin;
      VolumeBar.Enabled:=TRUE;
      VolumeBar.Position:=CurrentVolume;
    end else Begin;
      VolumeBar.Enabled:=FALSE;
      VolumeBar.Position:=0;
    End;
  except
     //removed for post
  End;
  VolumeBar.Tag:=0;
End;
```

any reason why this should not work?
I have the feeling that the OnChange event fires too late (after my UpdateVolumebar has already finished)... :-/

Comment: You're welcome to post a [mcve].

Comment: As an aside I'm fairly certain that you should not have an exception handler there, but you should have a finally to restore the tag value to zero.

Comment: Rather than using the `Tag`, you could alternatively just have `UpdateVolumeBar()` set the `OnChange` event to `nil` and then restore it before exiting. But more importantly, all of your `Begin;` statements are erroroneous, they should be just `Begin` instead (drop the trailing `;`) . I'm surprised your compiler is not complaining about that.